# Read large files line by line in Rust

Tags: rust

My Rust program is intented to read a very large (up to several GB), simple text file line by line. The problem is, that this file is too large to be read at once, or to transfer all lines into a `Vec<String>`.

What would be an idiomatic way to handle this in Rust?

Comment: @Kroltan - Not so much; this page is now the top ranking entry according to a Google search on "efficiently read lines from file in rust". (-:

Comment: @HuwWalters It was not at the time of posting! Current readers will be directed to any of those duplicates. And I'd dare say that SO posts still qualify as "examples" so the comment is still up-to-date (-:

Comment: That was my point; it's a useful page! (irony may have fallen a bit flat though)

Comment: I don't agree that this question has already been answered on SO and certainly not by the links present. OP specifically requested a method for *very large* files where the file is too large to be read at once or read line-by-line, a more efficient method must exist, which makes this a valid question

Comment: I searched for "rust read 1 line from a file" and arrived here. I must say, I've very disappointed on how difficult rust make it to read a line from a file. It's only a few lines of code in C#

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You want to use the [buffered reader, `BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html), and specifically the function [`BufReader.lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, BufReader};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    for line in reader.lines() {
        println!("{}", line?);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Note that you are **not** returned the linefeed, as said in the documentation.

---

If you do not want to allocate a string for each line, here is an example to reuse the same buffer:

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut reader = my_reader::BufReader::open("Cargo.toml")?;
    let mut buffer = String::new();

    while let Some(line) = reader.read_line(&mut buffer) {
        println!("{}", line?.trim());
    }

    Ok(())
}

mod my_reader {
    use std::{
        fs::File,
        io::{self, prelude::*},
    };

    pub struct BufReader {
        reader: io::BufReader<File>,
    }

    impl BufReader {
        pub fn open(path: impl AsRef<std::path::Path>) -> io::Result<Self> {
            let file = File::open(path)?;
            let reader = io::BufReader::new(file);

            Ok(Self { reader })
        }

        pub fn read_line<'buf>(
            &mut self,
            buffer: &'buf mut String,
        ) -> Option<io::Result<&'buf mut String>> {
            buffer.clear();

            self.reader
                .read_line(buffer)
                .map(|u| if u == 0 { None } else { Some(buffer) })
                .transpose()
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd8c177e683929be24e4cb672392f7c3)

Or if you prefer a standard iterator, you can use this `Rc` trick I shamelessly took [from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/d4rl3d/a_remarkably_simple_solution_to_the_problem_of/):

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    for line in my_reader::BufReader::open("Cargo.toml")? {
        println!("{}", line?.trim());
    }

    Ok(())
}

mod my_reader {
    use std::{
        fs::File,
        io::{self, prelude::*},
        rc::Rc,
    };

    pub struct BufReader {
        reader: io::BufReader<File>,
        buf: Rc<String>,
    }
    
    fn new_buf() -> Rc<String> {
        Rc::new(String::with_capacity(1024)) // Tweakable capacity
    }

    impl BufReader {
        pub fn open(path: impl AsRef<std::path::Path>) -> io::Result<Self> {
            let file = File::open(path)?;
            let reader = io::BufReader::new(file);
            let buf = new_buf();

            Ok(Self { reader, buf })
        }
    }

    impl Iterator for BufReader {
        type Item = io::Result<Rc<String>>;

        fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
            let buf = match Rc::get_mut(&mut self.buf) {
                Some(buf) => {
                    buf.clear();
                    buf
                }
                None => {
                    self.buf = new_buf();
                    Rc::make_mut(&mut self.buf)
                }
            };

            self.reader
                .read_line(buf)
                .map(|u| if u == 0 { None } else { Some(Rc::clone(&self.buf)) })
                .transpose()
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=58d67f799b7057e4d56f1de198c7e774)

Comment: Note that a new-line is considered to be a LF or a CR followed by a LF.

Comment: this isn't necessarily the most efficient way if the file size is greater than the available memory

Comment: @Awalias I updated my answer to be clearer. If you don't understand something specific, please say me what.

Comment: starting to learn Rust and this was super helpful and informative

Comment: Theoretically, could the line `Rc::make_mut(&mut self.buf)` be replaced with `Rc::get_mut(&mut self.buf).unwrap()` since we know it's available because we just made a new buffer with `self.buf = new_buf();`

I know it doesn't matter for this case but I'm implementing a buffer that stores the line into a struct from a csv. (And don't want to derive Clone for the struct).

Comment: What type does read_line return? It's not a string as I would have hoped for.

Comment: @AriesConnolly It's not a plain string, because sometimes the read can fail (`Some(Err(…))`), and after reading all the lines, it returns `None`.