# Why do I need to declare a variable at each iteration of a loop to use it?

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust from [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) and I just finished the first exercise, the [guessing game](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html).

I use `cargo` to build and run my little crate.

```sh
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.37.0 (9edd08916 2019-08-02)
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.37.0 (eae3437df 2019-08-13)
```

Everything run fine, including `release` mode. Nevertheless, I do not understand a the following behaviour of Rust: I have to redeclare the variable which contains the user input at each iteration of the loop.

Since the exercise is guided step-by-step, my code is the same that the one from the book. Nevertheless, the code from the book is the following:

```
loop {
    // Some code to display instructions.

    // Reallocate a new string at each iteration!
    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => continue,
    };

    // Some code to check if the player found the secret number.
}
```

Noticing this systematic reallocation, I moved the string declaration outside the loop:

```rust
// Allocate the string once.
let mut guess = String::new();

loop {
    // Some code to display instructions.

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => continue,
    };

    // Some code to check if the player found the secret number.
}
```

However, Rust did not appreciate this: at the second iteration of the loop, it panics every time.

Why can't I reuse the same mutable variable more than once? Do I not understand something?

EDIT: `read_line` does **not** clear the content of the previous input, but appends to it the following one.
Let's say the player enters `1` then `2`, the final value of guess will be `"1\n2\n"`.
However, `trim()` removes the "blank" characters at the beginning and the end of the string, leaving a `\n` in the middle: `parse()` panics!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code as-is compiles and runs fine on my setup (same version of rust). The panic must happen in the commented-out part of your code. Some comments, though: the scoping in your loop is tricky: `guess` at the top-half of the loop is the string declared outside the loop, and is the parsed integer in the second half.

More importantly, multiple calls to `read_line` being passed the same string appends to the string, which probably isn't your intention given the way you're parsing the string. Sprinkling in `println!`'s of your guess variables should be illuminating. Your code will probably be fixed if you add a `guess.clear()` on the string after you've parsed the number, but to do that, you'll probably want to rename the u32 `guess`.

As an aside, you might consider using a BufReader and the `for line in reader.lines())` pattern [described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882329/read-large-files-line-by-line-in-rust)

Comment: You are absolutely right, ```read_line``` appends the input to the previous string; the debugger showed me that at the second round - let's say, ```1``` then ```2``` - ```guess``` contains ```"1\n2\n"```.
```guess.clear()``` just before the input solves the problem! Thank you!

Comment: I edited my answer to include the fix: call guess.clear() before each read_line.