# Why do I need to collect into a vector when using `flat_map`?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm working on [Project Euler 96](https://projecteuler.net/problem=96) to teach myself Rust. I've written this code to read in the file and convert it into a vector of integers ([Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c71d801f1a19b0d1956913b4fd2dc1c2)).

```
let file = File::open(&args[1]).expect("Sudoku file not found");
let reader = BufReader::new(file);

let x = reader
    .lines()
    .map(|x| x.unwrap())
    .filter(|x| !x.starts_with("Grid"))
    .flat_map(|s| s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>())  // <-- collect here!
    .map(|x| x.to_digit(10).unwrap())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

This all works fine but I'm puzzled why I have to collect into a vector in my `flat_map` (I'm assuming creating unneeded vectors which will be immediately destroyed is inefficient). If I don't collect, it doesn't compile:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `s`
  --> src/main.rs:13:23
   |
13 |         .flat_map(|s| s.chars())
   |                       -^^^^^^^^
   |                       |
   |                       returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |                       `s` is borrowed here
```

The example from [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) shows almost the same code, but a collect is not required:

```
let words = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"];

// chars() returns an iterator
let merged: String = words.iter()
                          .flat_map(|s| s.chars())
                          .collect();
assert_eq!(merged, "alphabetagamma");
```

So why is it different in my code?

Comment: What's the format of the file you are reading? What if you try `.flat_map(|s| s)`?

Comment: The difference is that your code iterates over `String`s but the example iterates over `&'static str`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The iterator `reader.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap())` iterates over `String` items, i.e. by value. Consequently, in `.flat_map(|s| ...)`, the variable `s` has the type `String` (i.e. owned, not borrowed). In other words: the string is a local variable now and lives in the function. It's a simple rule that you cannot return references to local variables (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function/32683137)). But that's exactly what `s.chars()` does, even if it's a bit hidden.

Taking a look [at `str::chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars):

```rust
pub fn chars(&self) -> Chars<'_>
```

One can see that the string is borrowed. The returned `Chars` object contains a reference to the original string. That's why we cannot return `s.chars()` from the closure.

> So why is it different in my code?

In the documentation's example, the iterator `words.iter()` actually iterates over items of the type `&&'static str`. Calling `s.chars()` will also return a `Chars` object that borrows some string, but that string's lifetime is `'static` (lives forever), so there is no problem with returning `Chars` from that closure.

#### Solution?

It would be great if the standard library had an `OwnedChars` iterator that consumes a `String`, works like `Chars` and drops the string once the iterator is dropped. In that case it's fine to call `s.owned_chars()` because the returned object does not reference the local `s`, but owns it. But: such an owned iterator does not exist in the standard library!

> I'm assuming creating unneeded vectors which will be immediately destroyed is inefficient

Yes, that is true in a way. But you might have missed that the `reader.lines()` iterator also creates temporary objects of type `String`. Those are more or less immediately destroyed as well! So even without the `collect` in the `flat_map` you have a bunch of unnecessary allocations. Note that sometimes that's Ok. In this case, I guess that input parsing is very fast in comparison to the actual algorithm you have to implement. So ... just `collect`? It's probably fine in this case.

If you want to have high performance input parsing, I think you will not be able to avoid a standard loop, in particular in order to avoid unnecessary `String` allocations. ([Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eeb72bc2881dae67eb5c6c2180ec100e))

```rust
let mut line = String::new();
let mut input = Vec::new();
loop {
    line.clear(); // clear contents, but keep memory buffer

    // TODO: handle IO error properly
    let bytes_read = reader.read_line(&mut line).expect("IO error"); 
    if bytes_read == 0 {
        break;
    }

    if line.starts_with("Grid") {
        continue;
    }

    // TODO: handle invalid input error
    input.extend(line.trim().chars().map(|c| c.to_digit(10).unwrap()));
}
```

Comment: Superb answer thank you. Given it's just a toy example as you rightly point out performance doesn't matter, but I'm interested as a learning point so I know what to do when performance is important..

Comment: I've put a nice version of your loop in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882329/read-large-files-line-by-line-in-rust/45882510#45882510

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, note that an owned iterator is easy to write:

```
struct OwnedChars {
    s: String,
    i: usize,
}

impl Iterator for OwnedChars {
    type Item = char;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let c = self.s[self.i..].chars().next()?;

        self.i += c.len_utf8();

        Some(c)
    }
}

fn into_iter(string: String) -> OwnedChars {
    OwnedChars {
        s: string,
        i: 0,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let owned_iter = into_iter("Zażółć gęślą jaźń".into());

    for c in owned_iter {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

And then, you don't need to collect:

```
fn main() {
    use std::io::prelude::*;

    let file = std::fs::File::open(std::env::args().nth(1).unwrap()).expect("Sudoku file not found");
    let reader = std::io::BufReader::new(file);

    let x = reader
        .lines()
        .map(|x| x.unwrap())
        .filter(|x| !x.starts_with("Grid"))
        .flat_map(into_iter)
        .map(|x| x.to_digit(10).unwrap())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```