# How can I read a non-UTF8 file line by line in Rust

Tags: utf-8, rust

I'm trying to read a file one line at a time in Rust, and started by following the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882329/read-large-files-line-by-line-in-rust):

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file = File::open("countries.txt")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    for line in reader.lines() {
        match line {
            Ok(line) => println!("Ok: {}", line),
            Err(error) => println!("Err: {}", error),
        }
    }
    return Ok(());
}
```

However, I have non-UTF8 files.  The Python `chardet.universaldetector` library tells me this is ISO-8859-1:

```
Cuba
Curaçao
Cyprus
Czech Republic
Côte d'Ivoire
```

Out of the box, Rust is unable to interpret the lines with non-UTF8 characters:

```
$ ./target/release/main1 
Ok: Cuba
Err: stream did not contain valid UTF-8
Ok: Cyprus
Ok: Czech Republic
Err: stream did not contain valid UTF-8
```

So I tried the [encoding_rs_io](https://docs.rs/encoding_rs_io/0.1.7/encoding_rs_io/) library.  I'm using Windows 1252 here instead of ISO-8859-1, but it seems to work with this data:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

use encoding_rs::WINDOWS_1252;
use encoding_rs_io::DecodeReaderBytesBuilder;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file = File::open("countries.txt")?;
    let mut reader = DecodeReaderBytesBuilder::new().encoding(Some(WINDOWS_1252)).build(file);
    let mut buffer = vec![];
    reader.read_to_end(&mut buffer)?;
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8(buffer).unwrap());
    return Ok(());
}
```

This successfully reads the UTF8 characters:

```
$ ./target/release/main2 
Cuba
Curaçao
Cyprus
Czech Republic
Côte d'Ivoire
```

However, it does not have a `lines()` method, so cannot read one line at a time.  I note that the [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) project uses this library to decode non-UTF8 files, and I've stepped into its source code in a debugger.  As far as I can tell, it's doing its own hand-rolled CR/LF detection.

So, surely the task of reading non-UTF8 files one line at a time in Rust must have been solved already.  Do I really need to reinvent the wheel on this?  Help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: `DecodeReaderBytes` [implements `io::Read`](https://docs.rs/encoding_rs_io/0.1.7/encoding_rs_io/struct.DecodeReaderBytes.html#implementations), so you should be able to wrap it in a [`std::io::BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) and use [its `lines` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines).

Comment: Awesome, that works, thanks.  If you would like to put that in an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`DecodeReaderBytes` [implements `io::Read`](https://docs.rs/encoding_rs_io/0.1.7/encoding_rs_io/struct.DecodeReaderBytes.html#implementations), so you should be able to wrap it in a [`std::io::BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) and use its [`lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) method:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead, Read};

use encoding_rs::WINDOWS_1252;
use encoding_rs_io::DecodeReaderBytesBuilder;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file = File::open("countries.txt")?;
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(
        DecodeReaderBytesBuilder::new()
            .encoding(Some(WINDOWS_1252))
            .build(file));
    for line in reader.lines() {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
    return Ok(());
}
```